# Problems with Jquery Carousel for an MVC 4 application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue with my roundabout Jquery carousel plugin, and I've looked through some of the answers on here and still can't shift the problem.

So I have a Carousel that I'm trying to apply to my MVC 4 App, it is included in bundles like so:

```
  public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerycarousel").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.roundabout.js"));
```

and this is linked into my _layout page like so:

```
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerycarousel") 
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul').roundabout();
        });
```

I've tried it without using bundling (IE using basic HTML) as well as with Script rendering straight to the script source) but the problem remains the same!

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'roundabout'
```

In chrome inspector however, when I open up the header tags I can click on the roundabout.JS file and go straight to it, so it must be referencing it fine, this is also true of Jquery and these are the only two files needed!

Below is a picture showing the two 'linkable' script files and the document ready script.

[image: A view of the error in Chrome Inspector]

Javascript isn't my strong point :( So any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: after the page has finished loading have you tried running `$('ul').roundabout()` from the console to see if you get the error.

Comment: Yeah It comes up stating the same error, I take it this means the method doesn't exist inside the script then BAHH!!

Comment: are there any other errors except of that? see in Console

Comment: reading the docs it should work! are you sure it loads the js correctly? if possible provide a url

Comment: There is another error: Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. This is under Miscellaneous_bindings, But this happens on all my web pages, including this one!

Comment: @user1717715 which browser gives you this error? try also firefox please

Comment: On firefox it says TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function, I might download the script again to make sure i've got the correct one, this doesn't seem right at all

Comment: try this way plz: <script src="/Scripts/jquery.roundabout.js" onload="$('ul').roundabout();"></script>

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Do I have to include the script in order to get it to work? I feel maybe there's a step im missing somewhere?

Comment: Ok guys I seem to have fixed it. It turns out MVC 4 renders (references?) jquery for you at the bottom of the layout page just before the closing <body> tag, this for some reason caused it to not work, I've removed it and kept my rendered version at the top in the <head> tags, this seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I seem to have fixed it. It turns out MVC 4 renders (references?) jquery for you at the bottom of the layout page just before the closing  tag like so:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

This for some reason caused it to not work, I've removed it and kept my Script render version at the top in the  tags, this seems to have fixed the issue.

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem!